# Display DataTable with unknown numbers of column

Tags: jsf, datatable

I really would need your help in solving this problem am having with my project. Anyway, am new to JSF. Am working on a project and there is this module where examination records are displayed to students from a database upon successful authentication. This would be easy if all students are in the same class and offer the same number of courses, as you can create a dataTable model and then use it in your view. But in my case, the database contains tables for student’s exam records in different departments and classes like Computer Science 100,200 and 300 levels, Geology 100,200 and 300 levels and so on. These students also offer entirely different courses. Some offer physics, GST, computer and some don’t.

My problem is how do I display to different students their grades and course names in a dataTable dynamically.  Let me try and picture it.

100 level Computer Science table has 
CS101     CS102     GST101     MATH101     MATH102     PHY101     CHM101

200 level Computer Science table has
CS201      CS202     CS203   MATH201    CHM202
Please note the difference in the number of columns and names of column headers.

Then a Computer Science 100 level student wants to view his or her exam records, how do I display these records with the column names in a dataTable dynamically and not first creating a dataTable model with predefined column names. Not knowing the number of columns or names in advance. How do you do this for different students in different classes? I want a good code that will enable students from any department or level to login and then retrieve his exam records. Am not asking for the authentication code as that has been achieved, the code will display the names of the Database Table column headers and the records they hold for a particular 100 or 200 level. I need this because I don’t have to create a dataTable model containing specific column headers as i have many tables in the Database with different numbers of columns and names for different students departments and classes. Please I need your help and I hope I’ve been able to communicate my problem clearly. Am using JSF 2.1 (Facelets and Manage Bean), MySQL Database Server on NetBeans 7.2.1.

Comment: haven't read your entire question, but... is this what you looking for : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf (DataTable - Dynamic Columns)

Comment: @Daniel, thanks but that is not exactly what am looking for. I know my question is kind of lengthy but I was trying to explain it so you guys can understand. I wanted a code that works the way colleges display student’s examination records. Am not asking for the whole code but just the logic that makes such happens. I know it can’t be done by simply creating a model datatable and using it in your view. Pls try and read the problem statement so you’ll know what am driving at. Thanks again…

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and I am afraid that there's not possible way to fill a Datatable with unknown columns. You have to have the numbre in advance.
In my case, I found it easier to shift to JSP for this particular need and keep JSF for more "static" usage.
In my understanding, the only dynamic aspect of a Datatable is the numbre of rows.

One way to turn around this problem is using the rendered attribute of columns, in this case you'll put in every possible column and decide (via a bean, for example) to show or not some of them and hide some others.  This is semi-dynamic at best, but still is a livable solution.

Best of luck.

P.S : if wrong, please inform me of the solution because I would be curious to know it though unable to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Gloserio, am still researching and finding a way out. I’ll be sure to keep u posted if I finally find a way around it.

Comment: @GinoWine : thanks, make sure to study the possibility I suggested, rendered attribute can be a quite powerfull weapon !

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a **two** columned table

**First column** will be named: Course Code/Name

**Second column** will be name: Grade

Thats how it is being displayed in the Uni/College anyway...

To implement it just create an object with 2 `Strings` and populate a list of such objects... and that will be your `h:datatable` `value` attribute...

Comment: i intend recording Grades, Scores and GPA for just one course name. But i'll give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<Map<String, Object>>` to get hold of the data in a generic manner. Then you can use `<c:forEach>` to dynamically build columns (please note that `<ui:repeat>` is insuitable as it doesn't run during view build time, but during view render time).

Here's a concrete kickoff example, assuming that your environment supports EL 2.2:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.listOfMaps}" var="map">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.listOfMaps[0].keySet().toArray()}" var="key">
        <h:column>
            #{map[key]}
        </h:column> 
    </c:forEach>
</h:dataTable>
```

If you need the column labels in a separate collection as well (a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` is recommended for that as it maintains ordering), then instead do so:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.listOfMaps}" var="map">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.mapOfColumns}" var="column">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{column.value}</f:facet>
            #{map[column.key]}
        </h:column> 
    </c:forEach>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. Am sorry i already commented on your blog about this problem, i guess i was desperate to get your attention. I am going to apply your suggestion and if i encounter any problem i'll also comment back. Thanks...

Comment: Comments on blogs should relate to the blog article, not to something entirely different, else they may just be removed. If you have a question, just post it on a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow (as you found out).

Comment: i understand what you are saying. Am deeply sorry.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create column at runtime using backing bean method

```
public void loadDynamicList() throws Exception {

// Set headers (optional).
//dynamicHeaders = new String[] {"ID", "Name", "Value","delete"};

// Set rows. This is a stub example, just do your dynamic thing.
dynamicList = new ArrayList<String>();
/*dynamicList.add("One");
dynamicList.add("Two");
dynamicList.add("Three");
dynamicList.add("Four");
dynamicList.add("Five");
dynamicList.add("Six");*/

/*dynamicList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ID1","ID2" }));
dynamicList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ID1","ID2" }));
dynamicList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ID1","ID2" }));
dynamicList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ID1","ID2" }));
dynamicList.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ID1","ID2" }));*/

existingCountryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
String countryCode="SL";
existingCountryList.add(getCountryService().getCountryByCode(countryCode));
Country country=getCountryService().getCountryByCode(countryCode);
countryLanguageSet=country.getCountryLanguage();
int languageSize=country.getCountryLanguage().size();
dynamicHeaders = new String[languageSize+1] ;
int counter=0;
   for (CountryLanguage count: countryLanguageSet) {
    System.out.println(count.getLanguage().getLanguageName());
    dynamicHeaders[counter]=count.getLanguage().getLanguageName();
    counter++;
}
   dynamicHeaders[counter]="Delete";
   System.out.println("header list "+dynamicHeaders.toString());
   System.out.println("size"+dynamicHeaders.length);

}

public void populateDynamicDataTable() {
debugLogger.debug("populateDynamicDataTable:Enter");
// Create <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.dynamicList}" var="dynamicItem">.
HtmlDataTable dynamicDataTable = new HtmlDataTable();
dynamicDataTable.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#       {relationBean.dynamicList}", List.class));
dynamicDataTable.setVar("dynamicItem");
for (int count = 0; count < dynamicHeaders.length; count++) {
    HtmlColumn column = new HtmlColumn();
    HtmlOutputText header = new HtmlOutputText();
    header.setValue(dynamicHeaders[count]);
    column.setHeader(header);
if(dynamicHeaders[count].equals("Delete")){
    HtmlCommandButton commandButton=new HtmlCommandButton();
    commandButton.setValue("Delete"+count);

    commandButton.setActionExpression(createActionExpression("#{relationBean.deleteRow}", String.class));
    column.getChildren().add(commandButton);
}else{
    HtmlInputText input=new HtmlInputText();
    //List<String[]> ls = new  ArrayList<String[]>();
    input.setValueExpression("value",createValueExpression("#{dynamicItem}", String.class));
    column.getChildren().add(input);
   }
dynamicDataTable.getChildren().add(column);

}   
dynamicDataTableGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
dynamicDataTableGroup.getChildren().add(dynamicDataTable);
debugLogger.debug("populateDynamicDataTable:Exit");
}

public HtmlPanelGroup getDynamicDataTableGroup() throws Exception {
// This will be called once in the first RESTORE VIEW phase.
if (dynamicDataTableGroup == null) {
    loadDynamicList(); // Preload dynamic list.
    populateDynamicDataTable(); // Populate editable datatable.
}

return dynamicDataTableGroup;
}


public List<String> getDynamicList() {
return  dynamicList;
}
public void setDynamicList(List<String> dynamicList) {
this.dynamicList = dynamicList;
}


public void setDynamicDataTableGroup(HtmlPanelGroup dynamicDataTableGroup) {
this.dynamicDataTableGroup = dynamicDataTableGroup;
}

public ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression, Class<?> valueType) {
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(
    facesContext.getELContext(), valueExpression, valueType);
 }
public MethodExpression createActionExpression(String actionExpression, Class<?> returnType) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
    facesContext.getELContext(), actionExpression, returnType, new Class[0]);
}
private MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String valueExpression, Class<?> valueType,    Class<?>[] expectedParamTypes) {
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
        facesContext.getELContext(), valueExpression, valueType, expectedParamTypes);
}
```